Updating record field using VBA MS Access
I have a login page - but now I need a page to allow the user to change their password.
I have a table Users, with fields Login, User, and Password. Login is the primary key.
My account settings page shows the Login of the current user as a locked text box - this cannot be changed by the user.
There are two text boxes for the old and new password, named: txtOldPassword and txtNewPassword
When button btnChangePassword is clicked, I use a DLookup to determine if the old password is correct:
        If Nz((DLookup("Password", "Users", "Login = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")), "GarbageEntry") = Me.txtOldPassword Then
            
            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = txtNewPassword.Value WHERE [Login] = txtUsername.Value" '<--- Problem Line
            
            MsgBox "Password Changed, Please Log Back In"
            
            Me.txtOldPassword = Null
            Me.txtNewPassword = Null
            
            DoCmd.Close
            DoCmd.OpenForm ("Login Page")
        Else

I am doing something wrong with the CurrentDb.Execute line. I've tried each of the different answers provided here:
change a field's value with vba
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, when I replace the inputs with simple strings such as:
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = 'password' WHERE [Login] = 'first.last'", it works.
Not sure where I'm going wrong.

You must concatenate the input with the SQL like:
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Users SET [Password] = '" & Me!txtNewPassword.Value & "' WHERE [Login] = '" & Me!txtUsername.Value & "'"  

Side note: You should never store passwords as plain text. See my repository at GitHub:
Utilise Microsoft's Next Generation Cryptography (CNG) API in VBA
Storing passwords in VBA using the Microsoft NG Cryptography (CNG) API
